# iOS compiler error: IOKit/IOKitLib.h not found

Tags: iphone, ios, frameworks, build

I just tried to compile my xcode project for iPhone (using Phonegap).

Compiling fails though with this message:

```
In file included from 
    /Users
    /mobile
    /Documents
    /dev
    /mobile
    /ios
    /TOMO
    /xcode
    /TOMO
    /MyProject.de-Prefix.pch:25 
    (#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>):
In file included from 
    /Applications
    /Xcode.app
    /Contents
    /Developer
    /Platforms
    /iPhoneOS.platform
    /Developer
    /SDKs
    /iPhoneOS6.1.sdk
    /System
    /Library
    /Frameworks
    /UIKit.framework
    /Headers
    /UIKit.h:10 
    (#import <UIKit/UIAccessibility.h>):
In file included from 
    /Applications
    /Xcode.app
    /Contents
    /Developer
    /Platforms
    /iPhoneOS.platform
    /Developer
    /SDKs
    /iPhoneOS6.1.sdk
    /System
    /Library
    /Frameworks
    /UIKit.framework
    /Headers
    /UIAccessibility.h:8 
    (#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>):
In file included from 
    /System
    /Library
    /Frameworks
    /ApplicationServices.framework
    /Versions
    /A
    /Frameworks
    /CoreGraphics.framework
    /Headers
    /CoreGraphics.h:41 
    (#include <CoreGraphics/CGDisplayConfiguration.h>):

/System
/Library
/Frameworks 
/ApplicationServices.framework
/Versions
/A
/Frameworks
/CoreGraphics.framework
/Headers
/CGDisplayConfiguration.h:8:10: fatal error: 'IOKit/IOKitLib.h' file not found
#include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

So, obviously both, UIKit.framework as well as CoreGraphics.framework require IOKit, so I added IOKit.framework as a linked binary in:

```
Project->Build Phases->Link Binary with Libraries
```

And it's definitely there (I cann see IOKit.framework in my project navigator).

So, I clean and build and get the same error.

What gives?

Comment: Do you have the full iOS SDK installed? it looks like it's picking up the **desktop** `CoreGraphics.h` header, which uses the `CGDisplayConfiguration.h` header, while the iOS header does not look to use that file.

Comment: @Petesh Correct, I haven't read far enough.

Comment: @Petesh I think you're right that my project is referencing the wrong CoreGraphics.h but I don't understand why. I just re-installed xcode which ships with iOS SDK 6.1. I also linked CoreGraphics via this path: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework` which looks correct to me.

Comment: @Petesh I also tried to completely remove the link for CoreGraphics from my project but I still get the same error message (Shouldn't it be telling me that it's missing CoreGraphics now?). Something's really fishy here..

Comment: You should check the compile line that is being used to compile the code; it sounds like it is referencing a partial or incomplete SDK. if you compile it from the terminal using xcodebuild does the `-sysroot` get set to the appropriate value?

Comment: @Petesh sysroot is set to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk` - Looks ok to me. The full log trace of the compiling process is here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17844821/zeug/manualbuild.txt - Can't see anything suspicious there except that is uses the wrong CoreGraphics path: `/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CoreGraphics.h`

Comment: There is a comment in the PhoneGap docs: Some users have encountered compilation errors relating to missing headers. This refers to a problem in the build location and is fixed via Xcode preferences. Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations - choose `Unique` in the set of radio buttons.

Comment: @Petesh That dropdown is already set to "unique". However, I found an interesting string in xcode unter `Project->BuildSettings->SearchPaths->Release(Target)`. One of the default search paths was `"$(SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks"`. I simply removed that. I still get the same error in xcode but when I compile via command line, the error message is gone. In favour I get new funky messages (`Cordova/CDVViewController.h not found`). This is giving me a headache..

Comment: yeah, don't build with just `xcodebuild`, you need to build using something like: `xcodebuild CORDOVA_PATH=$(pwd) CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=$(pwd)/build`

Comment: @Petesh This is completely crazy. I just inspected my xcode project file (.xcodeproj) and opened project.pbxproj in there in order to check which path is set for CoreGraphics. It clearly states this line: `750E5BA416CBFC7E00A600F6 /* CoreGraphics.framework */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = wrapper.framework; name = CoreGraphics.framework; path = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework; sourceTree = "<absolute>"; };` Absolute path looks good. What the heck??

Comment: @H2CO3 You got any idea left? :-(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24463/discussion-between-petesh-and-valmar)